# Qt how to stop dragging viewport of QListView when using QScroller

Tags: qt, scroll, qlistview

I'm using QScroller on my QListView.

How can I stop dragging the list away when it reaches its beginning or its end?

Like image below.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the overshoot policy of the `QScrollerProperties`. Here an example for the vertical scrolling:

```
QScrollerProperties properties = QScroller::scroller(scrollWidget)->scrollerProperties();

QVariant overshootPolicy = QVariant::fromValue<QScrollerProperties::OvershootPolicy>(QScrollerProperties::OvershootAlwaysOff);
properties.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::VerticalOvershootPolicy, overshootPolicy);

QScroller::scroller(scrollWidget)->setScrollerProperties(properties);
```

Comment: Well, ty. I tried setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::VerticalOvershootPolicy , QScrollerProperties::OvershootAlwaysOff). It didn't work. It seems QVariant cast is necessary.